# CSS Scrolling with 100% width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey I have a problem with my website http://www.probeast-network.com/index.php

When you visit the site you'll be able to see a width of 100%, however, as soon as you start resizing the window you will see that the image which is set to width 100% doesnt change at all. I tried multiple things, however, I cant seem to figure it out. It might have something to do with the jquery slider, but this never caused any problems before. Here is the code

Script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.slider').each(function(ware) {
    $(this).cycle({
        timeout: 80000,
        speed:   400,
        sync:    false,
        pager:  '.pager',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i) {
            if (ware == 0)
                // for first slideshow, return a new anchro
                return '<a href="#">'+(i+1)+'</a>';
            // for 2nd slideshow, select the anchor created previously
            return '.pager a:eq('+i+')';
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="pos">
  <div class="pager"></div>

  <div class="slider"
  data-cycle-slider="> div"
  >

  <div class="size"><img class="imgsize" src="<?php echo $bild_giveaway;?>" alt=""/></div>

  <div class="size"><img class="imgsize" src="<?php echo $bild_video;?>" alt=""/></div>

  <div class="size"><img class="imgsize" src="<?php echo $bild_promine ?>" alt="" /></div>

  <div class="size"><img class="imgsize" src="<?php echo $bild_checkout ?>" alt="" /></div>

  <div class="size"><img class="imgsize" src="<?php echo $bild_tips ?>" alt="" /></div>

  </div>

  <div class="slider"
  data-cycle-slider="> div"
  >

  <div class="size1"></div>  

  <div class="size2"></div>

  <div class="size3"></div>

  <div class="size4"></div>

  <div class="size5"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#pos {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2;
margin: 0px auto;
}

.imgsize {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0%;
}

.slider {
width: 100%;
z-index: -95;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
opacity: 1;
}

.size {
position: absolute;
min-width: 1290px;
margin: 0px auto;
right: 0%;
z-index: -14;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 46px 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 46px 5px;
width: 100%;
min-height: 784px;  
}
```

If somebody knows a solution to this problem, please let me know. I have been troubleshooting for 6-7 hours now.. :(

Sincerely, Jan Breuer

Comment: @LGSon I think he wants it to resize if it is bigger than 1290px, the actual issue I think is div.slider has a fixed width for me, if I remove that in the Debugger it works for me.

Comment: @dav1d Not in his question, where it should be shown, but I took a quick look in the page and noticed it there.

Comment: When you post a question, make sure you post **all** necessary code with it, because when your site link will not be reachable, this question will be useless for future users.

Comment: Post a fully functional code snippet that reproduce the issue, or else all answers will be a wild guess.

Comment: @LGSon yeah, I know what you mean, I just thought it might be too much code for the side.. I haven't cleaned up unnecessary code yet, so there is a lot of code that probably isnt relevant, but thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your elements (.bottom, .lastline, .imagesheader, .menudiv, .....) get, a `min-width` set to `1290px` remove all the min width if you want the width "not scrolling"

Also your slider have a width set by javascritp so either you able to cancel the javscript function making the slider get a specific width either you cancel it with the css with the code below.

```
.slider {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Same for the class .size which get both the min width and the width set by javascritp.

Comment: The min width is supposed to be there.. so in case the window gets too small, then it is supposed to start scrolling, It has always been there and never caused any problems, however, since I edited the javescript function, it doesnt seem to work anymore

Comment: yep but this is the reason why the width doesn't fit the screen. if you tell the element to not be smaller than the min-widht it won't be. pretty logical right?

Comment: I have tried the code you recommended, however, it doesnt seem to work on my end :(

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add it to both, like you have mentioned, It now seems to work, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the div with class `.slider`, has some inline css set to it. More specifically it's width and height are set to `1290px` and `784px` respectively.